# Может ли android приложение получить доступ к блокировке экрана?

Tags: android

Есть идея сделать приложение, которое в зависимости от времени будет ставить другой пароль на телефон.Допустим, у пользователя стоит пароль на экране и если на часах 22:22 или 15:15, приложение не примет обычный пароль, а запросит другой.  Можно ли так сделать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Да можно, вам необходим доступ администратора в основе будет работать DevicePolicyManager, он позволяет проводить такие операции. 
Я дам пару ссылок, это должно помочь:

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/admin/device-admin#pwd

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/admin/DevicePolicyManager#resetPassword

за несколько последних лет Android сделал огромное кол-во изменений именно в политике безопасности, поэтому такие вещи будут иметь груду камней.